# dojo lazytreegrid is displayed differently in websphere portal 8

Tags: dojo, websphere-portal, dojox.grid

websphere portal 8 comes with default dojo 1.7.2, and this dojo documentation for lazytreegrid if for dojo 1.7 http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/grid/LazyTreeGrid.html

But when I run the example in the documentation, the treegrid is displayed like in image1. But when I use the same example, the treegrid is displayed in portal 8 differently(image2), which is quite ugly, how to get the same look and feel as in documentation

[image: documentation]

[image: portal8]

Comment: Have you done anything to see where the different styling is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example on the Dojo site is using "Claro" and your Portal site is using a different theme (I'm not sure which one, I think Soria).
The different themes can be loaded as modules in the Portal theme (not to be confused with the Dojo/Dijit theme).
Here's the wiki page:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+WebSphere+Portal+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Dojo_and_WebSphere_Portal_wp8&content=pdcontent

Look at this paragraph:
The tundra class is set on the body element in the portal Web 2.0 themes, and its corresponding CSS files are linked in as well. To use a different theme within a particular portlet, do not change the CSS classes of the body element from within the portlet because it has consequences on all other portlets and theme components that use Dijits on the page. Instead, use a separate node within the portlet to contain all the widgets used by that portlet, and assign the different theme class name on the container node inside the portlet.